# My Opel Astra 2000 1.6 randomly sometines Switches off whenever Moving from gear 5 downhill to Neutral

Tags: opel, astra

Hey guys I Urgently need help with my Opel Astra 1.6 2000 for I work with it..

It doesn't have HARD starting nor rough idle,but Tends to want to Switch off at times whenever Driving from Gear 5 to Neutral whenever going Downhill.... It occasionally drops The RPM below 500 sounds like It's about to switch off then jumps back up,whenever it does that at times the engine Light would come on the Disappears soon as the Car jumps from -500RPM to 1000RPM and at times it doesn't switch off completely,then Start it normally and It continuesjust fine now its Happening often.... with the little knowledge of cars I have I am suspecting My PCV or IACV??...

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track.  I would test the PCV valve by removing it and shaking it.  It should make a rattling sound if it is good.  If not, replace. I would also clean the IACV, throttle body and Mass Air Flow sensor (MAF) and remove any build up.  They have specific cleaners for those parts so do not use brake clean or any other harsh chemical. Keep us posted on how it goes.

**EDIT:**

These are the CRC brand cleaners I was referencing.

[image: CRC Cleaners]

Comment: Thank You very much.... what is Preferably used to Clean these??

Comment: I use CRC brand products (not a sponsor) for throttle body and IACV.  CRC also makes a MAF specific cleaner which I use.  I have had good luck with all their products.  There are other brands out there as well.  I would make sure you use a name brand product and not a one off brand.

Comment: Thank you for your Help... one last Question would The Opel Kardet IACV fit in my Opel Astra 2000 they look very alike

Comment: I could not find any information to confirm your question.  If they look similar and the fit is right I would give it a try.  I would try cleaning your existing IACV before going this route as they are easy to clean and it is the known right part for your vehicle.

Comment: Thank you so much for the valid information, another Question my Fuel regulator wouldn't open so I Changed it, Still doesn't open,Whenever the pipe between the ThrottleBody and Fuel Regulatorvalve is connected the car Switches off on itsel..What that Be caused by the faulty IACV and PCV?, Whenever Car Revved to 4000RPM stationary it takes out rich black smoke.

Comment: Glad to help.  It might be best if you start a separate question for your fuel pressure regulator issue.  There are many people much smarter then me that provide answers on this site, and you will likely get a variety of helpful answers.